# Can Token Registry be used for NFTs? Can I self-host a Token Registry?

Tags: nft

I just learned about the [token registry](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/cardano-token-registry/) by way of the [NFT docs](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts).

A few newbish questions:

1. It looks like the Token Registry is currently centralized, and I need to make PRs against github to add my own token to it.  Is this a correct?
2. Can this Token Registry also be used for NFTs? (I'm asking if it's technically possible, not whether the current PR-based approach can be scaled to suit this use case)
3. Will dApp developers eventually be able to host their own Token Registries?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes
2. Yes, but there two reason why it will most likely not be used for that: 1. There are sooooo many NFTs it would be unmanageable to maintain a github repo with that many PRs. 2. NFTs work perfectly already storing the associated data in the minting transaction's metadata.
3. You can fork it any time you like. YOu can propose a CIP for a different way to do this. There is a world of possibilities.